# EasyOCR - Table extraction

Tags: python, ocr, fine-tuning, easyocr

I use easyocr to extract table from a photo or scanned PDF, but I have a problem in fine tuning the data as a table.
I try to make a searchable pdf according to extracted coordinates but when I convert it to csv, the lines are not tune.
I would appreciate if someone guide me about this.

Comment: If possible please provide the image that you processing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you found a valid solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, easyocr currently does not support table recognition. The best table recognition should be PaddleOCR's PP-Structure model. This is what I use now, and the effect is very good. You can try it.

link: https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/dygraph/ppstructure/README.md

Comment: Can you share more info? which language you are recognizing table, how many images did you used for fine-tuning(if you had fine tuning).